# Android to router switch to desktop PC database

Tags: android, desktop

Can you connect the android app to your desktop PC and access the database thru wireless router/ WIFI ? Is this possible, without using any internet and web server as database? The reason for doing this kind of architecture is to be more secured and isolated. thanks for helping out.

Comment: How does one connect a software app with a hardware device? Unclear what you want in your first sentence.

Comment: "Is this possible, without using any internet and web server as database?" -- whether you use a Web service does not depend on where the Web service resides. Web services can be used on local hardware just fine, without Internet access. And, [using JDBC on Android is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).